Normalisers of Subgroups of $A_4$
I'm taking a course in topology and have no background in algebra. The course has been quite light touch on the algebra, but has slowly begun to include more as we've progressed. I'm going through an exercise, and have been finding myself getting stuck/bogged down on the "easy" parts due to not knowing how to compute things quickly. Apologies in advance if my lack of understanding shows too much.
Suppose we have a group $G$ with presentation $\langle a,b \mid a^3,b^3 , (ab)^2\rangle$. I believe $G$ is isomorphic to $A_4$ via the transform $$\begin{align*} a &\mapsto (2 \ 4 \ 3)\\
b& \mapsto (2 \ 1 \ 3)\end{align*}$$
I want to find the normaliser of each of the subgroups of $G$. I list out the elements of $G$ as $$\{e,a,a^2,b,b^2,ab,ba,ba^2b,ba^2,a^2b,b^2a,(ba^2)^2\}$$
I use that $G\cong A_4$ to derive that $G$ has $10$ subgroups: $$\begin{align*} H_1 &= \langle \rangle \\
H_2 &= \langle ab \mid (ab)^2\rangle \\
H_3 &= \langle ba \mid (ba)^2\rangle \\
H_4 &= \langle ba^2b \mid (ba^2b)^2\rangle \\
H_5 &= \langle b \mid b^3\rangle \\
H_6 &= \langle a \mid a^3\rangle \\
H_7 &= \langle a^2b \mid (a^2b)^3 \rangle \\
H_8 &= \langle ba^2 \mid (ba^2)^3 \rangle \\
H_9 &= \langle ab, ba,ba^2b \mid (ab)^2,(ba)^2,(ba^2b)^2\rangle \\
H_{10} &= G \end{align*}$$ To calculate the normaliser of each of these, I first note that $H_1,H_9$ and $H_{10}$ are normal subgroups, so $$N(H_1)=N(H_9)=N(H_{10})=G$$
Now, for the subgroups of $G$ associated with 2-cycles ($H_2,H_3,H_4$), I note that the normaliser of these subgroups cannot contain 3-cycle elements since only elements of the same order can be conjugate. Second, I claim that for any two 2-cycles, $x,y\in G$, we have $(xy)^2=e$ which implies that $x=yxy^{-1}$ so that all 2-cycles must be in the normalisers of these subgroups.
To prove this, consider first $(ab)(ba)=ab^2a$. As $(ab)^2=e$, $aba=b^2$ so $a^2ba^2=ab^2a$. Thus, $(ab)(ba)=a^2ba^2$, so $$[(ab)(ba)]^2=a^2ba^2a^2ba^2=a^2baba^2=a^3=e$$ where I have used that $a^3=(ab)^2=e$.
Next, consider $(ab)(ba^2b)=ab^2a^2b=(ab^2a)ab$. From the last paragraph, $ab^2a=a^2ba^2$, so $(ab)(ba^2b)=a^2ba^2ab=a^2b^2$. Because $(ab)^2=e$, $ba=a^2b^2$. Since $(ba)^2=e$, $ba=a^2b^2$. So, $$[(ab)(ba^2b)]^2=(ba)^2=e$$
Thirdly, consider $(ba)(ba^2b)=(ba)^2ab$. As $(ba)^2=e$, $(ba)(ba^2b)=ab$. So, $$[(ba)(ba^2b)]^2=(ab)^2=e$$
So, for any two 2-cycles $x,y\in G$, $x=yxy^{-1}$. Thus, $$N(H_2)=N(H_3)=N(H_4)=\langle ab,ba,ba^2b \mid (ab)^2,(ba)^2,(ba^2b)^2\rangle$$
For the 3-cycle subgroups, $H_5,H_7,H_8$, I am not sure how to proceed besides direct computation. I tried directly calculating for $H_6$ and found it was self-normalising. Is this to be expected? Or have I made a mistake? If it's not a mistake, can I prove all of these 3-cycles subgroups will be self-normalising?

Use \mid rather than | for the vertical bar in presentations, to provide additional space and improve readability.

@ArturoMagidin Done!

One small red flag for me in this outline: you say 'I use that $G\cong A_4$ to derive that $G$ has $10$ subgroups: [...]' but presumably that isomorphism is exactly what you want to prove! (Unless you're explicitly given that $G$ is isomorphic to $A_4$ and just want to prove that the transform given is one such mapping, but that seems a bit odd.)

@StevenStadnicki It does not sound to me like that isomorphism is what OP wants to prove. They are trying to find the normalizers of the various subgroups of $G$ -- potentially this problem arises from the context of covering space theory. Making use of this (correct!) isomorphism without proof seems fine to me.

@StevenStadnicki I have a proof that $G\cong A_4$ using the universal property of free groups and checking the normal closure of the relators is in the kernel of the associated homomorphism. My question is just about computation since I haven't seen the basic stuff needed to circumvent the laborious parts.

@diracdeltafunk You're right that this is coming from an exercise concerning covering spaces. The group $G$ is associated with some symmetries of a cuboctahedron and we're using the one-skeleton of the boundary as our universal cover.

My apologies for my misconception, then! Thank you for the info.

Great work so far! The most important idea is the following:
Let $\sigma \in S_n$ be a permutation, and consider any cycle $(a_1 \; \cdots \; a_k)$ in $S_n$. Then
$$\sigma (a_1 \; \cdots \; a_k) \sigma^{-1}  = (\sigma(a_1) \; \cdots \; \sigma(a_k)).$$
This general fact about permutations actually makes it pretty easy to compute the normalizer of a subgroup in $S_n$, $A_n$, etc! For example, let's take the subgroup you call $H_7$, which is $\{e, (1 \; 3 \; 4), (1 \; 4 \; 3)\}$.
We now see directly that if a permutation $\sigma$ normalizes $H_7$, then $\sigma$ fixes $2$ -- otherwise, either $1$, $3$, or $4$ would map to $2$ via $\sigma$ and $\sigma (1 \; 3\; 4) \sigma^{-1}$ could not equal an element of $H_7$!
Moreover, the only even permutations which fix $2$ are the elements of $H_7$.
We conclude that $N(H_7) = H_7$.

Ah! That is very clear. I had expected there was something basic I was unaware of which would make the computation easier. Thanks!
